# Symfony 2 default action for controller with ability to send response

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, controller

I listen to the kernel.controller action to implement a default (or init) action foo my controllers:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    if (!is_array($controller)) {
        return;
    }

    $currentController = $controller[0];
    if($controller[0] instanceof Initmethod){
        $ret = $currentController->init($event->getRequest());
        if($ret !== null && $ret instanceof Response){
            $ret->send();
            exit();
        }
    }

    $event->setController($controller);
}
```

As you can see, i want to give my init action the ability to return a response which should be send instead of the one of the called action. After that no other action should be executed.

My question is, is the way i'm doing it the right one? Because a don't want to "fight the framework" and ending the execution by calling exit doesn't seems do be right.

Comment: I have not tried your particular case but I would think $event->stopPropagation();return; should work in place of your exit(); Look at the bottom of this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html

Comment: In [`kernel.request`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-request-event) event you can use the [`setResponse()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/GetResponseEvent.php#L54) method to return a response immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `init` method of controller as current callable method e.g

```
$initController = array($currentController, 'init');
$event->setController($initController);
```

Then Symfony will process `init` method insted of default controller method and return the response if exists. I am assuming that you want to call the default controller method if `init` method returns `null`. In that case you can get method paremeters of that method using reflection, map function args and then invoke the method.

**Edit:**

It seems that I have misunderstood your problem. You want to avoid other listener operations like `kernel.view`, `kernel.response` etc. I think your solution is OK. But if you set session variable in your `init` method it will not be saved as it done by [ContextListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php#L96) which is called during `kernel.response` event.